# Azure Mobile Service error: more than one static class with name was found as bootstrapper in assemblies

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

The following error was reported in Azure logs after deploying a new version of C# MobileService project from Visual Studio 2013:

> More than one static class with name 'WebApiConfig' was found as bootstrapper in assemblies: {{My.MobileService.Project, myMobileService}}. Please provide only one class or use the 'IBootstrapper' attribute to define a unique bootstrapper.

If, in fact, there are multiple versions of mentioned class file, how do I clean it before deploying the new version?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This often happens when you change the name of your assembly. If this is the case, try removing the files in the destination. In the publish web dialog, expand the "File Publish Options", and select the "Remove additional files at destination" option when publishing.

[image]