# Azure Mobile Services Error: More than one static class

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I renamed my projects assembly, and now since I've changed it I now get this error.

> More than one static class with name 'WebApiConfig' was found as bootstrapper in assemblies: Restful, Service. Please provide only one class or use the 'IBootstrapper' attribute to define a unique bootstrapper.

I've came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27409000/azure-mobile-service-error-more-than-one-static-class-with-name-was-found-as-bo/27409399#27409399) post on Stack Overflow and followed it exactly, the error still remains. Could someone please help on which course of action I should now take to resolve this issue, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a applicable fix but after deleting the bin folder within project root, reverting the assembles back their original name and doing a re-build and push has resolved the issue. This might work for some people by deleting the bin folder, but it has worked for me.